# Is "cryptsetup" needed when changing files "crypttab" and "fstab" manually?

Tags: linux, encryption, disk-encryption

I'm setting up a new Linux host and want to have an encrypted SWAP partition. The file `/etc/crypttab` was missing, so I installed the package `cryptsetup`, which created that. Afterwards I simply edited that file manually using VI and additionally `/etc/fstab`, rebooted and encrypted SWAP was available. I updated the whole system, which resulted in the following error message:

```
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device rpool/ROOT/pve-1
cryptsetup: WARNING: Couldn't determine root device
cryptsetup: WARNING: The initramfs image may not contain cryptsetup binaries
    nor crypto modules. If that's on purpose, you may want to uninstall the
    'cryptsetup-initramfs' package in order to disable the cryptsetup initramfs
    integration and avoid this warning.
```

It's important to note that I didn't encrypt any other partition or anything, just SWAP. So I simply gave things a try and successfully rebooted. Afterwards I tried to do what the error message says and removed package `cryptsetup-initramfs`, which forced me to remove the package `cryptsetup` itself as well. The only things left were `cryptsetup-bin` and `cryptsetup-run`, which I removed by `apt autoremove` afterwards.

And here's what made me wonder: After a final reboot and with all those `cryptsetup` removed, I still seem to have encrypted SWAP. I have expected SWAP to not be available because of missing `cryptsetup`.

```bsh
root@pve:~# blkid | grep swap
/dev/mapper/swap_crypt: UUID="ccb3e6b9-ccaa-4c38-b34b-aa434134023c" TYPE="swap"
```

**So, I guess `cryptsetup` is really only about what the name says, setting things up? But not needed afterwards at runtime anymore? So it would have been fine to manually create `/etc/crypttab` right from the start using VI as well, without installing `cryptsetup` at all?**

Of course this is only because of my use case not needing to deal with `initramfs` etc. Though, I always had the impression that `cryptsetup` is needed during boot to properly setup e.g. SWAP as well.

Comment: FWIW this warning is normal on Debian and Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you still have a libcryptsetup package:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/libcryptsetup12

Systemd have its own builtin executable, which makes use of the library, that it uses to handle crypttab entries:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/cryptsetup/cryptsetup.c

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptsetup@.service.html

P.S. It might be worth mentioning that, if you have an encrypted root filesystem, and your initramfs init isn't systemd, you'll still need cryptsetup-bin et. al. to open/unlock the encrypted block device.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning cryptsetup is just a "frontend", the backend dm-crypt is in-kernel.

Comment: Correct, `libcryptsetup12:amd64` is still available. So the important thing is that systemd handles stuff at boot time and it's only about SWAP in my case, so I wouldn't have needed to install `cryptsetup` at all.

Comment: As long as there is no encrypted device that you are reluctant to add to crypttab, yes you can mostly rely on just systemd (you can add new entry and run `systemd daemon-reload` to generate new service instance for it, which you can start/stop with systemctl to open/close container mapper for the encrypted device)